# Sharedpreferences with switch button

Tags: android, switch-statement, sharedpreferences

I have a project, i want to save state of switch button on sharedpreferences. but it not working. Switch button always off when i switch activity or close app and reopen. what wrong in my code ? It working on first test, when i rebuid app again it wrong,

```
public class huongdan extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

Switch vt,mbf,vnp,vnm,gmb;
TextView vtmb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_huongdan);

    // hien thi man hinh float
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*1),(int) (height*0.80));
    // endhien thi man hinh float

    //switch viettel
    vt = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchvt);
    vt.setChecked(getFromSP("sw1"));
    vt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true){
                OneSignal.sendTag("viettel", "viettel");
            }
            else
                OneSignal.deleteTag("viettel");
        }
    });


    //switch mobi
    mbf = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchmbf);
    mbf.setChecked(getFromSP("sw2"));
    mbf.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true){
                OneSignal.sendTag("mobifone", "mobifone");
            }
            else
                OneSignal.deleteTag("mobifone");
        }
    });



    //switch vina
    vnp = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchvnp);
    vnp.setChecked(getFromSP("sw3"));
    vnp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true){
                OneSignal.sendTag("vinaphone", "vinaphone");
            }
            else
                OneSignal.deleteTag("vinaphone");
        }
    });


    //switch vietnammobile
    vnm = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchvnm);
    vnm.setChecked(getFromSP("sw4"));
    vnm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true){
                OneSignal.sendTag("vietnammobile", "vietnammobile");
            }
            else
                OneSignal.deleteTag("vietnammobile");
        }
    });

    //switch gmobile
    gmb = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchgmb);
    gmb.setChecked(getFromSP("sw5"));
    gmb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true){
                OneSignal.sendTag("gmobile", "gmobile");
            }
            else
                OneSignal.deleteTag("gmobile");
        }
    });

}
private boolean getFromSP(String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.sopu89.napthenoti", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}
private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.sopu89.napthenoti", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch(buttonView.getId()){
        case R.id.switchvt:
            saveInSp("sw1",isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.switchmbf:
            saveInSp("sw2",isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.switchvnp:
            saveInSp("sw3",isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.switchvnm:
            saveInSp("sw4",isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.switchgmb:
            saveInSp("sw5",isChecked);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the values from shared preferences and then set the button state in `onCreate` method

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true
if (tgpref = true) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
{
  tg.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
  tg.setChecked(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the onCheckedChanged-method in the end will never be called and therefore your states are not going to be saved.

The reason for this is, that you are declaring a new listener for every switch.
call

```
saveinSp("sw1", isChecked);
```

in the listener of switch one or set your class as listener for the switches and handle all changes there:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks @Katharina Sick

Comment: i change code to 'switch.setOnCheckedChangedListener(this);' this working, but i want settag and deletetag on every switch same my code when user change state of switch button, where i can put settag and deletetag code ?

Comment: great! sorry for not answering you yesterday - I didn't have time to check my computer